# How to turn my Delphi Class (from idHTTP) into a "Thread"?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have written a descend from idHTTP to implement my own communication class for various web-services.

> TidHTTP
>          |
>   TWebAPI
>      |
>   TWebOAuthAPI
>      |
>   TSpotifyAPI

Now that this all seems to work as I want it, I - of course - experience the delays of internet and thus have "hangs" in my application that use said classes as they wait for the timeouts of the idHTTP.
So the idea is to turn my class into a separate thread, so that at least the main programm doesnt stall. How would I go about that?

Should I turn WebAPI into a descend from TThread and have a TidHTTP Object in there, or have a wrapper later that uses a TSpotifyAPI Object??

Thx for any hints on that front :-)

Comment: Indy component library already has some multi-threading capabilities. So I would suggest you first check to see how it is done with existing Indy-s multi-threading implementation. The reason for this is that perhaps your custom component may already be compatible with Indy-s multithreading capabilities. That is off course if you haven't introduced any thread-unsafe code in your component.

Comment: You don't need to derive from TThread.

Comment: I don't think that `TIdHTTP` was designed to be derived. Although `TIdHTTP` is not a sealed class, you should prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understand that I should not derive from TidHTTP (and not from TThread either), but how, then should my class look like?  
TObject  
|  
TWebAPI
socket:tidHTTP  
|

?

Comment: Think about composition rather than inheritance

Comment: @PeterWolf there is no problem deriving from `TIdHTTP`. In fact, Indy encourages derivation, as many inner procedures are intentionally `virtual` to allow it. And even Indy's own `TIdWebDAV` is derived from `TIdHTTP`.

Comment: @WolfgangBures I would not suggest putting a thread inside of a `TIdHTTP` descendant, but rather just use `TIdHTTP` inside of a thread instead. Maybe someday you decide to change which HTTP library you want to use, then you can easily swap `TIdHTTP` with something else without breaking your code. HTTP should be considered an implementation detail of your component's internal workings, not an interface contract that the rest of your code has to abide by.

Comment: To finish this off, one last question: Is it wise to have the class run a permanent EXECUTE loop until terminated and somehow exchange data with the outside, or is it better to have my current functions (i.e. Spotify.PlayNextSong) to spawn a new thread and wait for the result of that to return data?

Comment: If you want to do some async processing from within the Spotify class, you should rather use some ‘ASync’ methods with a callback function to process the data when the call is done. Internally you can use asingle thread, but it’s also possible to use the TTask (when you have a newer) version of Delphi. The advantage of the TTask is that it’s automatically pooled.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TThread` descendant and use a TIdHttp component inside without problems, if you follow the normal rules when creating a `Thread`.

For some time I made a class to download images using Threads that included the TidHttp component without problems.

```
  {: Clase para descargar una imagen y almacenarla en disco.}
  {: Class to download a image and save it to disk}
  TDownImageThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FURLImage: string;
    FPathImage: string;
    FFileNameImage: string;
    // Internas
    ImageName: string;
    PathURL: string;
    // Componente
    idH:TidHTTP;
  public
    // redefinir métodos
    constructor  Create(AURL:string; AOutPathImages:string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
    {: URL de la imagen a descargar/ URL of the image }
    property URLImage:string read FURLImage write FURLImage;
    {: Path de disco local donde voy a almacenar la imagen/ Local path to save the image}
    property PathImage:string read FPathImage;
    {: Nombre completa (path+Nombre) de la imagen almacenada en disco local/Compete path on local}
    property FileNameImage:string read FFileNameImage;
  end;
```

The development is equal to others threads.
In this case is simpler, because it does not include a visual part, so you avoid problems related with synchronization.